# Assign value to a new column based on any of the multiple patterns from a vector

Tags: r

I have the following dataset called `df`:

```
structure(list(col1 = c("a b", "d e", "g f", "h j", "j k", "y z", 
"e f", "b c", "f g", "c d", "y z", "t u")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

For this dataset, I have two vector with matches: A vector called `matching1 <- c("a b", "b c", "c d")` and a vector called `matching2 <- c("c d","e f","f g")`. In my `df`, I would like to create a new column and assign a value for a match. For the vector `matching1`, I would like to assign a value of 1, for the vector `matching2` I would like to assign a value of 2 and for every string not matched a value of 3. Ideally, the value assignment for vector `matching2` would not change the previous value assigment because the vector `matching1` and `matching2` both feature the string `"d e"`. I know I can use:

```
matches1 <- paste0(na.omit(matching1), "", collapse = "|")
```

to create a collapsed vector with `or` and I have tried to combine it with `case_when`. However `case_when` does only allow single patterns and the list of potential matches in my original dataset is very long, so I would like to avoid spelling out every condition explicitely.

The output should look like this:

```
structure(list(col1 = c("a b", "d e", "g f", "h j", "j k", "y z", 
"e f", "b c", "f g", "c d", "y z", "t u"), col2 = c("1", "2", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "1", "2", "1", "3", "3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does it:

edit: performing match2, to catch the situation where  "c d" is in both, and match1 is preferred

```
df$ans<-ifelse(df$col1 %in% matching2, 2, 3)
df$ans<-ifelse(df$col1 %in% matching1, 1, df$ans)
```

Or pre-edit version with langtang's comment:

```
df$ans<-ifelse(df$col1 %in% matching1, 1, 3)
df$ans<-ifelse(df$col1 %in% setdiff(matching2, matching1), 2, df$ans)
```

Comment: perhaps use `setdiff` in your second line? `df$ans<-ifelse(df$col1 %in% setdiff(matching2, matching1), 2, df$ans)`

Comment: Great, thank you @M.Viking and @langtang. I have rarely come across the `%in%` operator, but will explore it a little bit more.

Comment: You can see the documentation at `?match`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using data.table, with a merge

```
library(data.table)

rbind(
  data.table(col1=matching1, col2=1),
  data.table(col1=setdiff(matching2,matching1), col2=2)
)[setDT(df), on="col1"][is.na(col2), col2:=3][]
```

Output:

```
      col1  col2
    <char> <num>
 1:    a b     1
 2:    d e     3
 3:    g f     3
 4:    h j     3
 5:    j k     3
 6:    y z     3
 7:    e f     2
 8:    b c     1
 9:    f g     2
10:    c d     1
11:    y z     3
12:    t u     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to solve your problem:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(col2 = case_when(col1 %in% matching1 ~ 1, 
                          col1 %in% matching2 ~ 2, 
                          TRUE ~ 3))

   col1 col2
1   a b    1
2   d e    3
3   g f    3
4   h j    3
5   j k    3
6   y z    3
7   e f    2
8   b c    1
9   f g    2
10  c d    1
11  y z    3
12  t u    3

Or

library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, col2 := fcase(col1 %in% matching1, 1, col1 %in% matching2, 2, default=3)]

      col1  col2
    <char> <num>
 1:    a b     1
 2:    d e     3
 3:    g f     3
 4:    h j     3
 5:    j k     3
 6:    y z     3
 7:    e f     2
 8:    b c     1
 9:    f g     2
10:    c d     1
11:    y z     3
12:    t u     3
```